# Laravel throws the error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-6

In my view file Home.blade.php, I am printing out my image using this tag:

```
 <img src="{{$post->imageUri}}" alt="image" class="uploadedpic">
```

But it throws a Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED console error and the image doesn't load.

Here's my controller code:

```
$request->validate([
        'place'=>'required',
        'image_path'=> 'required|image'
    ]);

    $imageName = Storage::putFile('public', $request->image_path);

    $post = new Post;
    $post->place = $request->get('place');
    $post->image_path = $imageName;
    $post->user()->associate($request->user());
    

    $post->save();

    return redirect('/home');
```

and here's my model code:

```
public function getimageUriAttribute()
{
    return Storage::url($this->image_path);
}
```

Kindly help me figure a way to get that image working!!

Comment: And what is the value of your `img` tag `src` if you view the source of your page?

Comment: http://localhost:8082/storage/A5l7WpiyyMt3HVE6vKhWSIn1AQ7OJRwig2qEYhiY.jpg 404 (Not Found)

This